# How to avoid three clicks to get into src/main/webapp in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, eclipse-wtp

I am setting up a maven web app project in eclipse, maven likes to put the webapp resources in `src/main/webapp` which is a pain to navigate to because I have to click three times to get to webapp contents.

- click 1 expand src
- click 2 expand main
- click 3 expand webapp

[image: Example of three levels of clicks needed to navigate to webapp]

In a typical WTP eclipse project there is only WebContent and is a top level folder so only one click is needed to get into it.

Is there an eclipse or m2e trick to make the webapp show up as a top level element under the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the webapp folder and select `Build Path -> Use as Source Folder`. The folder will be presented on top (in a hierarchical package presentation). It should have no side effects to the final war.

[image]

Comment: I used to do this, but actually it is a bit ugly because webapp is then handled as a source folder for Java classes, so it's just a hack.  According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1664247/1620264 it must be possible to set it as a Web Resources folder, but I couldn't figure out how to do that yet

Answer (score 5):

If it makes your life easier, you can override the webapp directory location to hang directly off `${basedir}`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```